# Chrome Extension Input Text Issue

Tags: javascript, web, google-chrome-extension, html, dom-manipulation

Can anybody help us out? We have created a extension to search a text box for key words and if a keyword is found we then want to write text into another text box. We aren't sure how to create a second send response (or even if it is a send response we need) within the content script or how to access it in the background script. Code listed below.

Content Script:

```
// Listen for messages
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function (msg, sender, sendResponse) {
console.log(msg);

// If the received message has the expected format...
if (msg.text === 'report_back') 
{
    // Call the specified callback, passing
    // the web-page's DOM content as argument

    sendResponse(document.getElementById('.........').innerHTML);
} 

});
```

Background Script:

```
var urlRegex = /^https?:\/\/(?:[^./?#]+\.)?stackoverflow\.com/;

// A function to use as callback
function doStuffWithDom(domContent) {

var search = false;

if (domContent.match(/......./gi))
{
    window.alert('......');
}
else
{
    var r = confirm("Search indicates no tasks listed!");
        if (r == true) {

            //Type Text Code

        } else {

            x = "You pressed Cancel!"; //We are aware this does not do anything
        }
}

}

// When the browser-action button is clicked...
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function (tab) {

 // ...check the URL of the active tab against our pattern and...
    // ...if it matches, send a message specifying a callback too

    chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tab.id, {text: 'report_back'}, doStuffWithDom);

});
```

Manifest:

```
{
"manifest_version": 2,
"name": "Test Extension",
"version": "0.0",


 "background": {
 "persistent": false,
 "scripts": ["background.js"]
 },
  "content_scripts": [{
  "matches": ["*://*.com/*"],
 "js": ["content.js"]
  }],
  "browser_action": {
  "default_title": "Test Extension"
   },

   "permissions": ["activeTab"]
   }
```

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding what you mean by "create a second send response".  When you send a message, you send the response function as well.  If you need another response function, why not send another message?  Or have the original response function do both jobs?  (And please pick a title more useful than SOS.)

Comment: Hi @Teepeemm , thanks for taking a look. We have never programmed in JS before so we are kind of spitballing here but we tried to make a second send message and couldn't get that too work. 

The original response function does input the text we require but we don't want it to input the text upon the chrome extension being clicked we want to create an OK button inside of the window alert that will input the text upon that button being clicked.

I hope this makes sense.

Thank you,

Comment: My recommendation would be to figure how you would do this with regular javascript, and then try to turn it into an extension.  I'm still having trouble figuring out what you want to do.  You have a search text box.  If the search text is found, then do you want to write text to another text box?  Why does that need a background script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not put the logic in background script to content script? Since you are merely searching the dom and popup an alert window.

Content Script:

```
var doStuffWithDom = function (domContent) {
    if (domContent.match(/......./gi)) {
        window.alert('......');
    }
    else {
        var r = confirm("Search indicates no tasks listed!");
       if (r == true) {

           //Type Text Code

        } else {

            x = "You pressed Cancel!";
        }
    }
};

chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function (msg, sender, sendResponse) {
    if (msg.text === 'report_back') {
        doStuffWithDom(document.getElementById('.........').innerHTML);
    }
});
```

Background Script:

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function (tab) {
    chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tab.id, { text: 'report_back' });
});
```

Comment: Hi thank you for getting back to us, we have tried to do this before but this way does not work for us either. All of our logic works as it is we just don't know how to create another piece of logic that will run in the content script and be called in the IF TRUE statement within the background script. We tried making another 'chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener' in the content then calling it in the IF statement using 'chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tab.id, {text: '....'});' but nothing.

Comment: @CameronCharlton But the only logic you've shown in your background script is looking at the tab's url.  You can do that from the content script.

Comment: @Teepeemm ignore what I said before, this work perfectly. Thanks a lot for all the help and feedback. It now searches the text box for any matching key words and if none are found writes into a text box for me.

Answer (score 0):

Seems you are searching Dom content from the background HTML page?
Are you sure the content is within the background page?

Your content script is executed "within" (actually sandboxed) browsed HTML pages.
I guess you should search the DOM from the content-script...

Comment: It looks like `doStuffWithDom` is searching the dom, but that happens in the content script when the alias `sendResponse` is called.